# Prevent apt-get from updating a package

Tags: debian, apt

I compiled `vim` with some specific options and don't want it to be updated by `apt-get` as I need to recompile it always. How could you do that?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package – does that work for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [this Ask Ubuntu post](https://askubuntu.com/a/18656/17529) the easiest way to hold a specific version of a package (i.e. prevent it from updating):

```
sudo apt-mark hold vim
```

You remove the hold with:

```
sudo apt-mark unhold vim
```